# Firestore returning deleted documents in queries

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, geofire

I'm using [GeoFirestore](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android)'s `GeoQueryDataEventListener`.

At the moment, I'm testing with 2 devices. `User1` searches to see if any other documents are nearby with [GeoQuery](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android#geo-queries) - if no documents exist then it creates a new document. Then `User2` will search and find User1's document.

The problem is, when `User2` performs a GeoQuery, it will often return documents that have been deleted.

**I do not want to retrieve documents from the cache.** If the document does not exist on the server, I do not want it returned. I have turned off cache persistence in my code:

```
val settings: FirebaseFirestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().setPersistenceEnabled(false).build()
val db by lazy { FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() }

db.firestoreSettings = settings
```

However my `GeoQuery` still returns documents from cache.

Having said this, most of the time `GeoFire` says a document is from the cache but it is not:

**Example 1** - The following document with `z2sniJhKrWpZhX` ID was deleted. I then queried the DB and that document was returned in `onDocumentEntered`:

```
nearbyUsers = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(currentLocation, 1.0)
nearbyUsers.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(object : GeoQueryDataEventListener {

override fun onDocumentEntered(documentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot, location: GeoPoint) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDocumentEntered: user1: ${documentSnapshot.getString("user1")} | docId: ${documentSnapshot.id} | fromCache: ${documentSnapshot.metadata.isFromCache}")

onDocumentEntered: user1: 6IXCuAzK76JWP7F3h414IShm1 | docId: z2sniJhKrWpZhX | fromCache: true
```

**Example 2** - The following document with `yRFjKHEyGXclKcS` ID was **not** deleted. I then queried the DB and that document was returned in `onDocumentEntered`:

```
nearbyUsers = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(currentLocation, 1.0)
nearbyUsers.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(object : GeoQueryDataEventListener {

override fun onDocumentEntered(documentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot, location: GeoPoint) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDocumentEntered: user1: ${documentSnapshot.getString("user1")} | docId: ${documentSnapshot.id} | fromCache: ${documentSnapshot.metadata.isFromCache}")

onDocumentEntered: user1: 6IXCuAzK76JWP7F3h414IShm1 | docId: yRFjKHEyGXclKcS | fromCache: true
```

Both documents were apparently from the cache even though one was live on the server.

All I want is to perform a `GeoQuery` ([`GeoQueryDataEventListener`](http://GeoQueryDataEventListener)) that returns live documents (no cache). If this isn't possible, I'd be happy to filter based on `documentSnapshot.metadata.isFromCache` - but even that is not possible because sometimes it says the document is from cache even though it isn't.

Any advice is appreciated.

**Edit:** If I retrieve a document from `onDocumentEntered()` - it's usually from cache on the first go. Then if I perform `GeoQuery.removeAllListeners()` then go again, the same document will be retrieved but not from cache. [In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDvdAFP6OhQ&t=144s) it says I should receive the second callback from the server if I am connected to the internet - however I have to query the database in a seperate call. I need the document retrieved from the server (not cache) on the first try. How can I achieve this?